# default value of textbox not changed after typing different value to it

Tags: javascript, html

I assigned default value to textbox after the value passed by query string from
previos web page.

it looks like that:

```
<form method="post" name="create" onsubmit="return checkPercentValue()" style="font-size: medium; margin-top: 10%" dir="rtl" >
<input type="text" size="5px"  id="stocksPercents" name="stocksPercents" value="@stocks">
</form>
```

Now when the user typing another value to the textbox for change the default one,
I call for javascript function to validate the value in some range (0 - 100).

the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkPercentValue() {

    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("stocksPercents").getAttribute("value"));
    if (value > 100 || value < 0) {
        window.alert("please insert value between 0 - 100");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }

}
</script>
```

So I checked why when I put value for example: 200 (greater then 100), the alert doesn't pop up(!!!)
I added to the code this line:

```
document.write(value);
```

And I saw the value allways stay the default one....and will not changed even I changed it in the
textbox before.

So I guess the problem is that typing value into the textbox can't change the default value 
just like that...

what the solution to that?

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("stocksPercents").getAttribute("value"));
```

With

```
var value = parseInt(document.getElementById("stocksPercents").value);
```

This will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider using jQuery. The syntax is easier, much shorter to type, and cross-browser compatible (that is, you don't need to worry about this b/c jQuery guarantees that for you.)

Here is your code in jQuery:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkPercentValue() {
            var value = parseInt($("#stocksPercents").val());
            if (value > 100 || value < 0) {
alert('I am GREATER');
                window.alert("please insert value between 0 - 100");
                return false;
            }
            else {
alert('I am LESS');
                return true;
            }

        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#stocksPercents').blur(function() {
                checkPercentValue();
//              alert('Yo!');
            });
        });
        </script>    
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" name="create" onsubmit="return checkPercentValue()" dir="rtl" >
    <input type="text" size="5px"  id="stocksPercents" name="stocksPercents" value="@stocks">
</form> 


</body></html>
```